# Efficient pagination with Oracle database using QueryDSL

Tags: java, database, oracle, querydsl

I have a table with a large amount of records in an Oracle database. Assume the table looks like this:

```
+--------+----------+-------+--------+
| Column |    Id    | Value | Active |
+--------+----------+-------+--------+
|        | 1        | 123   | Y      |
|        | 2        | 234   | Y      |
|        | 3        | 12345 | N      |
|        | 4        | 98765 | Y      |
|        | ...      | ...   | ...    |
+--------+----------+-------+--------+
```

I would like to fetch those records with Active marked as 'Y' page by page for processing with multiple threads (1 page per thread).

To achieve this, I can execute the follow query:

```
SELECT Value FROM MyTable WHERE Active = 'Y' OFFSET 1000 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Or use the following codes in Java:

```
QMyTable myTable = QMyTable.myTable;
jpaQueryFactory.select(myTable.value)
.from(myTable)
.where(myTable.active.eq('Y'))
.offset(1000)
.limit(1000)
.fetch();
```

However, the performance of this query degrades because the database has to go through all previous records and throw away those out of the range.

For a better performance, I can use the follow query:

```
SELECT Value FROM MyTable WHERE Active = 'Y' AND Id > 1000 FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Java:

```
QMyTable myTable = QMyTable.myTable;
jpaQueryFactory.select(myTable.value)
.from(myTable)
.where(myTable.active.eq('Y'))
.where(myTable.Id.gt(1000))
.limit(1000)
.fetch();
```

The above code works but the performance still degrades (first page took 0.1 seconds but after 3M records it took 7 seconds!). Am I doing it wrong? Or any other ways I can use to speed it up?

Comment: [Well, offset pagination is not a very good idea in the first place](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago, a project in my company tried exactly what you are doing. Not only did their attempt fail, but the **project** failed.

Here are some of the dangers you may run:

- The data changes while your processing is taking place, and everything doesn't get processed.
- Since you don't have an `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT`, you get some rows twice and some not at all.
- If you don't have the right indexes in place, every query does a full scan of the table.
- If you do use an index, the query still goes to the table for all the rows up to and including the rows you want. That is probably why the query slows down as you go through the pages.

I strongly suggest you rethink your overall solution, so as to do the processing in the database if you can. Use DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE if you need "do-it-yourself" processing (requires version 11.2 I think).

I will still try to answer your question as asked.

Most pagination requirements are different from yours! They want to send the first few pages to a user interface. You want to break all the active rows down into pages. The most efficient way to do that is all at once. For example:

```
create table t ( id, active, val) as
with actives(active) as (
  select 'Y' from dual union all
  select null from dual union all
  select null from dual
)
, vals(val) as (
  select level from dual
  connect by level <= 1000
)
select rownum, active, val
from actives, vals,
(select null from dual connect by level <= 1000);

select count(*) from t;

 COUNT(*)
---------
  3000000
```

Now create an intermediate table with one row per page, indicating a ROWID range for each page.

```
create table pages(page primary key, start_rowid, end_rowid) as
select * from (
  select * from (
    select rowidtochar(rowid) rid,
    ceil(row_number() over(order by rowid) / 1000) page,
    mod(row_number() over(order by rowid), 1000) is_start
    from t
    where active = 'Y'
  )
  where is_start in (1, 0)
)
pivot(max(rid) "ROWID" for is_start in (1 as "START", 0 as "END"));
```

That created 1000 rows for 1000 pages in 1 second. Now let's see how many active rows there are in the last page.

```
select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ count(*) from t t
join pages p
  on t.active = 'Y'
  and p.page = 1000
  and t.rowid between p.start_rowid and p.end_rowid;

  COUNT(*)
----------
      1000
```

That took less than 1/100th of a second.

Here is the execution plan for that query. Notice the TABLE ACCESS BY ROWID RANGE step, and the small amount of buffers accessed.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name         | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows | Buffers |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |              |      1 |        |      1 |      13 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE               |              |      1 |      1 |      1 |      13 |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                |              |      1 |   2500 |   1000 |      13 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PAGES        |      1 |      1 |      1 |       3 |
|   4 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | SYS_C0012519 |      1 |      1 |      1 |       2 |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS BY ROWID RANGE| T            |      1 |   2500 |   1000 |      10 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```